# Add blog posts in a Nuxt content blog

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I want to create a blog using nuxt since I am familiar with vue js. I have looked at nuxt content module. I understand that i can create markdown blog posts. But, I am confused. If I deploy the app, then How can I add new blog posts?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You add the posts **before** deploying, in your source code, as described in [Nuxt Content's documentation](https://content.nuxtjs.org/writing). Then you have to build the Nuxt project and (re)deploy the site.

If you need the ability to edit your blog after deployment, in your browser, and redeploy it after every editing automatically, you would need a service which has access to the source code and has ability to build & deploy your site. [Netlify CMS](https://www.netlifycms.org/) can be one such solution, (especially) if your site's source code is on GitHub. (It works with private repositories too.)

Comment: Ok I got it. Thank you.